# Can't use Cargo to build hello world example from Rust tutorial

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I followed the Rust book/tutorial on the Rust page at, http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/hello-cargo.html, and get the below error when doing the section on Cargo. The command was `cargo build --verbose`. I used the verbose flag because of a failure in the build process. It looks like Cargo is trying to build a file named "verbose".  I did use the verbose flag; it's almost like the arguments sent to rustc are missing a `--` prefix?

```
Process didn't exit successfully: `rustc -v verbose` (status=101)
--- stderr
error: couldn't read verbose: IoError { kind: FileNotFound, desc: "couldn\'t ope
n path as file", detail: Some("file not found (OS Error 2: The system cannot fin
d the file specified.\r\n); path=verbose; mode=open; access=read") }
```

The Cargo.toml file contains this text:

```
[package] 

name = "hello_world" version = "0.0.1" 
authors = [ "Your name <you@example.com>" ] 

[[bin]] 

name = "hello_world"
```

The computer I am running is Windows 7 64 bit using the 64 bit nightly install from 2 days ago 1/18/2015.

Comment: Also, you should always give us your exact command which resulted in this output.

Comment: Make sure you ran `cargo build --verbose` and not `cargo build -- verbose`

Answer (score 1):

I just followed the [tutorial](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/hello-cargo.html) you linked, and I don't see any reference to using the verbose flag. I assume that you looked at the help for Cargo or otherwise learned about it.

However, when I followed the first two steps ("Hello, world!" and "Hello, Cargo!"), I was able to run `cargo build --verbose`.

I think you will need to provide more information about your particular setup.

Comment: See above I did use cargo build --verbose. I also tried cargo build -v. It appears that when rustc is evoked. Cargo uses the arguments "-v verbose" this results in rustc trying to build the non existent file verbose. If I  rename the file "src/main.rs" to "verbose" the build completes and I get an executable named "verbose.exe". I am confused why I did not get a file named "hello_world" though?